# Internet Explorer 11 makes non required field required

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer

I have a product registration form with several fields on it and Internet Explorer 11 makes a non required field required.  I removed the JavaScript form validation and there is no events triggered on the form or the field. Right now for debugging purposes it is just doing a straight form post.  This only happens in Internet Explorer 11, not in Edge, Firefox or Chrome or Opera.  The form post never happens, IE just put the focus in the field and there is no message of any kind.

This is the form field that is causing the problem. Any ideas at all on this?

```
<input type="text" name="ship_to_zip_code" value="" id="ship_to_zip_code" maxlength="6" placeholder="Zip/Postal Code" />
```

Comment: From the input code you've provided, I'm sorry I could not reprodcue your issue. It seems that the code is normal. Could you please share the code that could reprodcue your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I finally tracked this down to some old JavaScript code we had buried for support for Internet Explorer 8 and 9 so that we could use the placeholder attribute with those browsers.  I just removed the old JavaScript code since we no longer have to support those crappy browsers and everything is fine.